# Problema. No muestra los datos de Base de Datos MySQL

Tags: eclipse, jsf, jpa, maven

Estoy comenzando una aplicación Java Web con Java SE Development 64 bit (Versión 8, compilación 1.8.0)
 con JSF, JPA, Maven en Eclipse Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a.) Spring
 Base de Datos en MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE. Apache Tomcat v8.5 Server.

Como dije estoy comenzando, así que busqué un tutorial, y al realizarlo. No me muestra los datos.
 No he logrado identificar donde puede estar el error. Si alguien puede ayudar por favor. Muchas gracias.

En la Consola, no aparece ningún error.
Al hacer clic en Run As/Run on Server. La pagina http://localhost:8080/JSF-Project/  muestra solo los encabezados:

Lista Clientes 
 Id   Nombre   Rut   Razón Social   Giro   Dirección   Teléfono Editar

Archivo: persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
  version="2.1">

  <persistence-unit name="PERSISTENCE">
    <description> Crud Hibernate JPA</description>
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/basedatos_schema" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="xxxxxx" />
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
    </properties>

  </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Archivo pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.emaus.projectjsf</groupId>
  <artifactId>JSF-Project</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>JSF-Project Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.9-rc</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>JSF-Project</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.20.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Necesitaríamos más información como si se ha generado la base de datos y si esta tiene valores. Si no los tiene, puede que esté todo correcto y por ese motivo solo te muestre los encabezados.

Comment: Si. La BD existe. Tiene datos.

Comment: Pon más código como el jsp, servlet..